# SSRS: Plotting only a specific product on a chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm currently building a report which will show the weight of a specific product throughout the day on a chart. The problem I'm having is that the SQL code pulls the weights of all the products rather than only the one I want. As a result, when I plot the data it shows me the weights of all the products throughout the day. I was wondering if anyone knew how I should approach plotting the data.

The fields I am working with are named: "Product_description" and "Weight"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can either edit the query to take a parameter from the report and use it in the where clause in your SQL statement, or you can that same parameter and use it in the filter properties of the chart itself. If this doesn't help, post some sample data and you expected output and we'll be able to help further,

Comment: This worked, thanks!